# get value from nested json array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, nested

I have the follwoing being returned by a json call:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [so] => SO0040024
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [coid] => 4824
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sdkstatus] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [sdkstatus] => pass
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [invoicenumber] => INV0063955
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [invoiceamount] => 9437.24
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [invoicestatus] => pass
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [invoicestatus] => fail
        )

)
```

How do I extract each value out of the array? for example I want invoicenumber, INV0063955.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Why is it multidimensional? Theres no need to. Try to flatten the output so you can loop through it more easily.

Comment: Why do some keys appear twice, like `sdkstatus` and `invoicestatus`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a horrible way to structure your data. Instead of nesting each property in its own array, they should be keys of the main array. But if you're stuck with it:

```
foreach ($array as $element) {
    if (isset($element['invoicenumber'])) {
        $invoicenumber = $element['invoicenumber'];
        break;
    }
}
```

You could also turn it into a more sane associative array like this:

```
$newarray = array();
foreach ($array as $element) {
    foreach ($element as $key => $value) {
        $newarray[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

However, this won't deal with the repeated keys, it will just save the last one. I'm not sure how this is supposed to be handled in your data. Maybe those elements should actually be arrays of values?